# Getting 500 error while sending post request of multipart-form type

Tags: go, web-services, multipartform-data

I want to send multiple files in html field in a multipart/form data type request in golang. Below code is what I am using.

```
func RenderAndUploadToS3(files []*multipart.FileHeader, browserName string, paths string, screenshotHeight int, screenshotWidth int, buildId string) error {
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(&buffer)
    defer writer.Close()
    numberOfFiles := len(files)
    logger.InfoLog("The number of stories to be rendered for buildId: " + buildId + " is " + strconv.Itoa(numberOfFiles))

    for i := 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++ {
        f, err := files[i].Open()
        if err != nil {
            logger.ErrorLog("Failed to open file for buildId:" + buildId + " due to " + err.Error())
            return err
        }
        // Create a file field
        formFile, err := writer.CreateFormFile("html", files[i].Filename)
        if err != nil {
            logger.ErrorLog("Failed to create writer for file for buildId: " + buildId + " due to " + err.Error())
            return err
        }
        _, err = io.Copy(formFile, f)
        if err != nil {
            logger.ErrorLog("Error while copying file contents into writer for buildId: " + buildId + " due to " + err.Error())
            return err
        }
        f.Close()
    }

    _ = writer.WriteField("browserName", browserName)
    _ = writer.WriteField("paths", paths)
    _ = writer.WriteField("height", strconv.Itoa(screenshotHeight))
    _ = writer.WriteField("width", strconv.Itoa(screenshotWidth))
    _ = writer.WriteField("buildId", buildId)
    url := constants.DOTUI_HOST + constants.DOTUI_RENDER_ROUTE_V2
    logger.InfoLog("The url for sending dotui request is " + url)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &buffer)
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorLog("Failed to do POST request for buildId: " + buildId + " due to  " + err.Error())
        return err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorLog("Failed to do POST request due to  " + err.Error())
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        logger.ErrorLog("Failed to read POST response body from screenshot-render api v2 for buildId:" + buildId + "due to  " + err.Error())
        return err
    }
    logger.InfoLog("The response from screenshot-render api v2 for buildId: " + buildId + " is " + string(b))
    return nil
}
```

The above code is giving 500 error. The express service where this api is located is logging empty request object.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question for the following reasons. 1) The target service is responding with 500 which is supposed to indicate an internal server error; usually such status is reported for _hard_ errors–such as an exception raised due to sloppy programming,–but still nothing prevents the service return 500 just because its creators are insufficiently educated on these matters or due to other reasons…

Comment: 2) The code per se does not display any obvious problems but at the same time it has several properties which might be problematic–as an example, having form field for each of the multiple attached files be named "html" appears to be strange. The form fields also carry no `Content-Type` information, and so on. At the same time, one cannot say wheher any of these points can cause trouble _with your particular server_ because no one is failiar with it and has access to its documentation…

Comment: So, the only sensible way to work this out is: 1) read the service docs, if avaiable; 2) dump what you POST and see whether it matches the service's expectations; 3) start small–that is, start posting a single file or no files at all, and see whether it works; 4) try different things such as fix the points I mentioned above; 5) get in touch with the folks who have programmed the server and discuss the problem with them.

Comment: It worked. just had to add ```err := writer.Close()```